# run multiple instances of Sage Line 50

Tags: windows-7, multiple-instances, sage

A client of ours run the Sage Line 50 accounting software.  Normally this software doesn't allow you to run more than one instance.  However on WinXP we found that we could run another instance by using a script to run a second instance with the runas command.  This no longer appears to to work on Win7 64 bit.

What is interesting is that if you switch users you can run the same program twice each running as a separate user.  I'm guessing that the reason is that the processes cannot see each other when they are in separate sessions while they are visible when run in the same session.

Any ideas on whether it is possible to trick the program into thinking there are no other running processes?

Comment: `Normally this software doesn't allow you to run more than one instance` - It sounds like you're trying to violate the EULA.

Comment: Have you tried running a renamed copy of the .exe?

Comment: @joeqwerty admittedly I haven't read the EULA but the intent is not to violate it.  It is for convenience for staff whose time is split between two companies in a shared office environment.

Comment: @WhoIsRich thanks for the suggestion.  I'm pretty useless at remembering to write down the things I have tried.  Although I think it can also limit other people's brainstorming ability.  Anyway to answer your question, I did try renaming the executable and it didn't help.

Comment: While not as slick as RunAs, a handy trick is you can remote desktop to your own PC using 127.0.0.2 and be logged as a different user. This would avoid having to keep switching between users.

Comment: @WhoIsRich It doesn't quite work for me on Win7_64.  It says that the number of connections is limited and all are in use now (paraphrased).  I've read in the past that you can change this setting for non-servers but from memory it involved editing a binary file with a hex editor.

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot about that, not hex editing, running a 'universal termsrv.dll patch' that's available, but that may not be pratical for your place.

Comment: My other thought, if it's checking the running processes, you could try running the second copy as a non admin account with UAC on to limit what it can see.

Comment: @WhoIsRich thanks for the update on the termsrv patch.  I did some googling and discovered the same thing (but was a bit dubious about installing random binaries from the internet...).  I would've liked to up vote your answer but can't.  Its worth adding your idea as an Answer for people browsing this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have found to the problem is to run at least one of the instances in a sandbox.  I tested using the free version of Sandboxie (http://www.sandboxie.com) and it seemed to work when I ran a second instance in the sandboxed environment.  Not sure if the order they are instantiated matters.

Edit: If using Sandboxie it will by default try to copy all files used by an application into the sandbox.  This is not what you want in a shared database situation!  So to fix there are settings in Sandboxie to allow direct access to particular files or folders.  I set the directory holding the Sage DB to be directly accessible.